# How to Implement the ICommand as DependencyProperty

Tags: binding

I am using the implementation give at [Bind TextBox on Enter-key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563195/wpf-textbox-databind-on-enterkey-press) to handle the enter key for text box.

But I am using MVVm pattern for my application. Therefore I have defined the `ICommand` handler in my `VieModel` class. I want to bind it to view.

The sample application uses

```
InputBindingsManager.UpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed="TextBox.Text"
```

and I want to use

```
InputBindingsManager.UpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed="{Binding myCommandHandler}"
```

instead.

Can anybody suggest what modification are required in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for inputbindings for a textbox. in this you can bind a Icommand object to command property ok keybindings

Here is the sample code

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Firstname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <TextBox.InputBindings>
                            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ValidationCommand}">
 </KeyBinding>
                        </TextBox.InputBindings>
                    </TextBox>
```