# Change Source of Binding for attached property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, attached-properties

If I use binding extension in attached property

```
<TextBlock local:MyBehavior.View="{Binding A}" /> <!-- or B -->
```

How can set value of `A` (or `B`) property of ViewModel from that attached behavior?

I do not understand:

1. Which type to use for attached property? `Binding`? `BindingBase`? `BindingExpressionBase`? `object`?
2. Shall I set the value immediately? Shall I wait for some event? Shall I use another dependency property to set it's value, then bind to `SomeProperty` and let binding do the job once `DataContext` is set?

My failed attempt is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41612129/1997232), for convenience I copied it below:

```
public class MyBehavior
{
    public static BindingBase GetView(DependencyObject obj) => (BindingBase)obj.GetValue(ViewProperty);
    public static void SetView(DependencyObject obj, BindingBase value) => obj.SetValue(ViewProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("View", typeof(BindingBase), typeof(MyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
        {
            var element = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (element == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Only used with FrameworkElement");
            element.Loaded += (s, a) => GetView(element); // <<
        }));
}
```

I am not sure what to do at marked line to set value of given by binding property:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public object A { get; set; }
    public object B { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify your question: do you want to set the `ViewModel`'s `A` property in the `OnPropertyChanged` callback of a dependency property that is bound to that `A` property? That makes no sense.

Comment: @dymanoid, this is why I am here. I am not sure how to organize that using attached property. If e.g. I'd use `bool` and set `local:MyBehavior.View="True"` - then this will cause callback to run, where I can do something like `((ViewModel)element.DataContext).A = something`. Now I want that `A` to be defined in the xaml. Therefore binding. And the question which doesn't make sense ;)

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11121057/1997232).

Answer (score 1):

> Which type to use for attached property?

The same type as you have defined the source property in the view model with, i.e. `object` or whatever type of value that the attached property should store. The type depends on the type of value you intend to store in the attached property.

> Shall I set the value immediately

You can specify a default value for a dependency property when you register it. The default value for a reference type such as object is typically `null`:

```
public class MyBehavior
{
    public static object GetView(DependencyObject obj) => obj.GetValue(ViewProperty);
    public static void SetView(DependencyObject obj, object value) => obj.SetValue(ViewProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("View", typeof(object), typeof(MyBehavior), 
            new PropertyMetadata(/*default value: */ null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The value of the dependency property will be set automatically when you bind to the view model just like any other dependency property, e.g.:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public object A { get; set; } = "value...";
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<TextBlock local:MyBehavior.View="{Binding A}" />
```

---

```
public class MyBehavior
{
    public static object GetView(DependencyObject obj) => obj.GetValue(ViewProperty);
    public static void SetView(DependencyObject obj, object value) => obj.SetValue(ViewProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("View", typeof(object), typeof(MyBehavior), 
            new PropertyMetadata(/*default value: */ null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        object theValue = GetView(d);
        MessageBox.Show(theValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to set the view model property to the value of your attached property you should set the Mode of the binding to `OneWayToSource`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name local:MyBehavior.View="{Binding A, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

But then it is the view that updates the view model:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    MyBehavior.SetView(txt, "new value...");
}
```

The attached dependency property isself is just another dependency property that can be set on any DependencyObject.

**Edit:**

> This solution still require code-behind, my intent to eliminate it with attached behavior. Ideas? Notice element.Loaded (see also my comment to @dymanoid), idea was to set the value from attached behavior and only use binding to pass source (defining which property, A or B, should get that value).

Then you could simply set your attached property to the name of the source property:

```
<TextBlock local:MyBehavior.View="A" />
```

...and use reflection to set the value of this source property in your attached behaviour:

```
public class MyBehavior
{
    public static object GetView(DependencyObject obj) => obj.GetValue(ViewProperty);
    public static void SetView(DependencyObject obj, object value) => obj.SetValue(ViewProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("View", typeof(object), typeof(MyBehavior), 
            new PropertyMetadata(/*default value: */ null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Only used with FrameworkElement");
        element.Loaded += (s, a) => 
        {
            string propertyName = GetView(element).ToString();
            if(element.DataContext != null)
            {
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = element.DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                pi.SetValue(element.DataContext, "new value...");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution still require code-behind, my intent to eliminate it with attached behavior. Ideas? Notice `element.Loaded` (see also my comment to @dymanoid), idea was to set the value from attached behavior and only use binding to pass source (defining which property, `A` or `B`, should get that value).

Comment: Haven't though about reflection, thanks. However binding is more flexible: I can bind to parent control context, by `ElementName`, providing converters, validation, etc..  My **only** problem is to figure out what type `View` should be (btw, in last edit version it's better to use `string`) and how to set source value (what you do with reflection now). Ideas? ;)

Comment: What type View should be depends on the type of the source property. If the source property can be any type, the View property should be an object.

Comment: Agree. This is true if you want to call `SetValue()` on that dependency property (which in turn will set source of the binding). But what if you call `GetValue()` to get something (in your last edit it's a name of property, in my failed attempt it's a binding as `BindingBase`) and **then** do something with it to set something. Does this makes it more clear? You see, with reflection you are currently passing the **name** of property. I was thinking to rather pass directly source.. as a binding.. and there I stuck.. I have binding, but don't know what to do with it to set its (binding?) source.