# databound textbox not updating unless selected

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a static singleton class with properties I use to databind textboxes to.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Masca
{
    public class logged : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {    
        public static logged instance = new logged();
        public static logged Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }

        private string alisa;
        public string aliasname
        {
            get { return alisa; }
            set
            {
                alisa = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("aliasname");
            }
        }

        private string mail;
        public string emailadd
        {
            get { return mail; }
            set
            {
                mail = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("emailadd");
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

This is the property access method:

```
loggedin.Instance.emailadd = "email.text";
```

This is the datacontext I place in the initialize components of all other pages I wish to access the property:

```
DataContext = loggedin.Instance;
```

and this is the XAML code for a bound TextBox

```
<TextBox x:Name="email" Text="{Binding emailadd}" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11" Margin="134,417,0,0"/>

<TextBox x:Name="mail" Text="{Binding emailadd}" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11" Margin="134,435,0,0"/>
```

The problem is that if I type something into email.text, mail.text will only reflect what is in email.text once i have clicked in mail.text.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `UpdateSouceTrigger`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="email" Text="{Binding emailadd, 
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                               Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Note that the default value of `UpdateSourceTrigger` for a `TextBox.Text` is `LostFocus`, while for many other properties, it is `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: To think I spent all morning turning my project up side down trying to figure this out... Thanks King.

Answer (score 2):

if you're trying to trigger the binding for each key stroke you will need to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger`.

```
<TextBox Name="itemNameTextBox"
    Text="{Binding Path=ItemName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

this SO answer describes some more scenarios (eg. filtering the key pressed)
[Bind TextBox on Enter-key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563195/bind-textbox-on-enter-key-press)