# Update data binding by Enter Key in code behind WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a FrameworkElementFactory works like a textbox created in the code, so there is no xaml code, and also I set this textbox with data binding in code. Now I want to update this textbox databinding by **Enter** key pressed. I have read one way for attached behavior in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563195/bind-textbox-on-enter-key-press), but it seems working with xaml code. Is there any way to set attached behavior in code behind?

```
ListBox DDF_List = new ListBox();

FrameworkElementFactory Editable_TextBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
Binding text_binding = new Binding("Value");
Editable_TextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, text_binding);

DataTemplate Text_Layout = new DataTemplate();
Text_Layout.VisualTree = Editable_TextBox;
DDF_List.ItemTemplate = Text_Layout;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should almost certainly be doing this with a `DataTemplate` in XAML. What you've got is a prefect case for doing everything in XAML. But if you're committed to doing it the hard way, here's how.

With your `FrameworkElementFactory`, you can set it like any other dependency property on a `FrameworkElementFactory`:

```
Editable_TextBox.SetValue(
    InputBindingsManager.UpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressedProperty, 
    TextBox.TextProperty);
```

More generally, here's now to apply that attached property to a `TextBox` in C#, where `itemNameTextBox` is the TextBox:

```
InputBindingsManager.SetUpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed(itemNameTextBox, 
    TextBox.TextProperty);
```

---

With attached properties, this C#:

```
var itemNameTextBox = new TextBox { Name = "itemNameTextBox" };

var binding = new Binding("ItemName")
{
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};

itemNameTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

//  This is the line you're asking for:
InputBindingsManager.SetUpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed(itemNameTextBox, 
    TextBox.TextProperty);
```

Is an exact equivalent of this XAML:

```
<TextBox 
    Name="itemNameTextBox"
    Text="{Binding Path=ItemName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    b:InputBindingsManager.UpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed="TextBox.Text"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. But can I use Frameworkelementfactory to replace the "itemNameTextBox" in this context

Comment: @SamXia Absolutely. The call to `InputBindingsManager.SetUpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed()` is the only part of my code you need -- just pass that your textbox, however you created it. I just did all that stuff to justify my claim that it was "an exact equivalent to the XAML". I'll update to clarify the point.

Comment: No, I mean I use FrameworkElementFactory type to replace TextBox type in input, but it tells me the FrameworkElementFactory is not DependencyObject

Comment: `FrameworkElementFactory` isn't a `TextBox`. I don't understand what you are doing at all. Please add enough code to your question for me to understand what you are doing.

Comment: What is InputBindingsManager? is it a part of Telerik WPF?

Comment: @Sorush Google says Telerik.